# How to add wordpress includes and login management to custom module?

Tags: php, wordpress, constructor, include

I am building a Wordpress site with the Constructor theme. I had to add custom coding to solve my goals. There is a module, that let's the user add children elements to his profile, that will be saved to database. (create, update, delete) This functionality is done with the following files in:

```
wp-content\themes\constructor\crud\
 destroy_user.php,
 get_users.php,
 save_user.php,
 show_form.php,
 update_user.php
```

These files at the moment have no includes, they are only called from a custom coded page template. So far they work.

Now I would like to develop this module to handle multiple users. For this I would need to know who is using the module. This I know at the custom page template, but not at the code in ex. get_users.php . For example I would like to use

```
$user_id = get_current_user_id();
```

in get_users.php to control the sql and redirect the user if he is not logged in. **What files and how must I include, to be able to use get_current_user_id()?**
(Simply include '../../../../wp-includes/user.php' does not solve it.)

Thanks for the help,
Sziro

Edit: this is wp-content\themes\constructor\crud\get_users.php

```
<?php

    $page = isset($_POST['page']) ? intval($_POST['page']) : 1;
    $rows = isset($_POST['rows']) ? intval($_POST['rows']) : 10;
    $offset = ($page-1)*$rows;
    $result = array();

    include 'conn.php';
    require('../../../../wp-blog-header.php');
    $user_id = get_current_user_id(); //This does not work. If it would be set to = 1, it would work.


    $rs = mysql_query("select count(*) from user_partner where user_id=$user_id");
    $row = mysql_fetch_row($rs);
    $result["total"] = $row[0];
    $rs = mysql_query("select * from user_partner where user_id=$user_id limit $offset,$rows");

    $items = array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_object($rs)){
        array_push($items, $row);
    }
    $result["rows"] = $items;

    echo json_encode($result);


?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end it was solved with an iframe. Not very safe, but at least presentable.

Answer (score 1):

So currently a Wordpress theme includes and uses this files. And you want to create another/use the same php file to include Wordpress' functions?

You can include Wordpress functions by:

```
<?php
    require('/root_of_wp_installation/wp-blog-header.php');
    //or     require('../../../../wp-blog-header.php');
    get_categories();
?>
```

Comment: Basically yes.
Your suggestion did not solve the issue. I have included the code in my post.

Comment: In your post? it won't work there, this is included in your php files.

Comment: Somehow, the required() function crashes. Ex $user_id = 1 runs fine, require('../../../../wp-blog-header.php'); $user_id = 1; crashes.

Comment: You'll need to check the correct path to wp-blog-header, it should be at wordpress root installation.